# How to globaly add library path to QT creator?

Tags: qt, installation

I have QT5 installed on an external usb hard drive. In my pro file, initially, I have no `-L` library paths but when I compile it automaticly places

```
-L/media/UsbExternalDrive/DesignTools/Qt5.3/5.3/gcc_64/lib
```

when it compiles. I need to have it search `-L/usr/lib` and would not like to have to add `LIBS += -L/usr/lib` to the .pro file for every project. I have looked at some options but am unable to find a place to insert a library search path for the whole QT creator program so that any project will look in that place. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Is this a UNIX system? `-L/usr/lib/` should be automatically searched by the linker.

Comment: Thats what I thought!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is what I found out and what seems to of fixed this. I don't think

> /usr/lib

was being searched by the linker. I don't know why. It may be because I had QT5 installed on an external hard drive connected by usb 3.0 port. So after manually adding the

> -L/usr/lib

to the .pro file I was able to compile just fine and find

> libGL.so

. I then was trying to recreate the problem but when I remove the

> -L/usr/lib

from .pro file I can still compile. I can now create projects and the linker searches and find the library just fine. Not sure why this works but it does. I assume it has more to do with the back in make file system than I understand.